# Alert if variable contains non numeric characters?

Tags: javascript, regex

'p' can only store "$", commas, dots or numbers.

How can I show an alert if it contains any other character?

Comment: -1 (What have you tried? Should know the drill by now...)

Comment: And by the way the title doesn't match the question body...

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
if (p.match(/[^$,.\d]/))
    alert('error!');
```

[**Live DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/k2ApK/)

You can use [this](https://www.cheatography.com/davechild/cheat-sheets/regular-expressions/) **Excellent** regex cheat sheet.

Answer (score 6):

Consider:

```
if (/[^$,\.\d]/.test(p)) {
  // value has characters other than $ , . 0-9.
};
```

The regular expression *test* method returns a boolean value, whereas *match* returns an array and so is dependent on type conversion when used in a simlar manner.